# Could using Java.IO.File cause data to scramble on an AS400 IFS?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, ibm-midrange, java-io

I am building a small java application that will take in XML files and convert them to text files. The end result being a jar that sits on the IFS to convert files when called from a shell script run by a RPGLE program. (Not my idea, just charged with making it happen)

To do so I am using JAXB to unmarshall these XML files into JAXB annotated POJOS before putting them into a text file using the a new IFSFile and IFSFileOutputStream. **This works great with the exception that the order output data is scrambled or out of its proper order.**

I created a second version of the Jar that replaced the IBM Toolbox classes for standard Java.IO classes. **This version of the jar when run from Windows outputs the results in the proper order.** This same Jar (Java.IO version) run from the 400 itself returns scrambled data too.

Both Jars however use a standard Java.IO file for the XML inputs. This is because JAXB will not accept an IFSFile as an input. See the below code:

```
File inputFile = new File(source);
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(PriceRecords.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
PriceRecords priceRecords = (PriceRecords) unmarshaller.unmarshal(inputfile);
List<PriceRecord> data = priceRecords.getPriceRecords();
```

I read somewhere that the AS400s save/read files differently than a standard Linux or Windows OS would. So I am wondering if someone can shed some light on this. If the scrambled data isn't caused by the above inputFile being the Java.IO.File class used on a AS400, what else could cause this difference in functionality?

Comment: what version of IBM i?  Are you up to date on PTFs for Java?

Comment: The JVM in IBM i (fka OS/400) supports the standard Java.IO.* classes including the Java.IO.File class.  You don't have to use the IFS classes in JT400.

The only difficulties I'm aware of is dealing with the EBCDIC/ASCII/Unicode conversions.  

Are you running the Java program on the IBM i server, or on a PC and connecting to the IBM i server?

Comment: Thanks for the responses Charles. I am running it on the 400 itself via strqsh. The operating system is 7.1.

Comment: Found the answer! In windows some of the fields that had no data were blank where as on the 400 they returned NULL. Once I had fixed the null fields to not be null the data unscrambled.

Comment: You don't say exactly how the data is "scrambled". There are generally two reasons for seeing different ordering on two systems. (1) Natural lexicographic sort order is different. This is common when one system is EBCDIC and the other system is not. (2) The language specification doesn't guarantee a fixed ordering, and different implementations do different things. This is common for intrinsically unordered collections, such as associative arrays (in most languages), SQL result sets without an ORDER BY clause, and so forth.

Comment: Consider updating your question to include an example of the "scrambled" output and then posting the answer yourself.  You are allowed to answer your own questions.  It may help the next person.